# Perform Espresso view action on SurfaceView

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have a class `GameView` extended from [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). I added this view in activity_main layout like this:

```
gameView = new GameView(MainActivity.this);
activity_main = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
activity_main.addView(gameView);
```

Now I want to perform any view action (i.e. click) on this SurfaceView using Espresso UI test. So far I came up with this:

```
DataInteraction surfaceView = onData(instanceOf(GameView.class))
.inAdapterView(withClassName(is("android.view.SurfaceView")));
    surfaceView.perform(click());
```

But this is not the right way cause it gives the following error:

`android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with class name: is "android.view.SurfaceView"`

How can I find the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using getName() solved the problem.

```
ViewInteraction surfaceView = onView(withClassName(equalTo(GameView.class.getName())));
    surfaceView.perform(click());
```

Comment: or use [isAssignableFrom()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html) built-in `ViewMatcher`